# Select a specified number of digits following a pattern

Tags: regex

I need a regex to select a part of a string. Possible strings:

```
"Til.: 1231231231 Fax: 1231231231 Kin.: 1231231231"
"Til.: 1231231231"
"Til.: 1231231231 Kin.: 1231231231"
```

In all these occasions I need to select the 10 digits following the "Fax: " string if it exists.

Comment: Can you precise the language, as stipulated in the tag description ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex :

```
Fax:\s?(\d{10})
```

As you didn't precise the language I can only suggest you to test it in the console of your browser; type this :

```
"Til.: 1231231231 Fax: 1231231231 Kin.: 1231231231".match(/Fax:\s?(\d{10})/)
```

Comment: Won't this include `Fax:` in the match?

Comment: @arshajii All regex libraries let you get both the match and the submatch. In case of JS, this will be the element with index 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was sure there was a faster way than trying to learn regex right now...StackOverflow FTW. Again thank you so much.

Comment: @user1299106 You **still** should learn regexes. I hope I helped you learn. Is there something unclear in my answer ?

Comment: No sir. It works flawlessly. Still i need to deliver something in 2 days and that 3 minute work of yours saved me from a lot of headache under pressure..Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`

```
grep -oP "(?<Fax: )[^ ]+"
```